# Converting a number to s string in JavaScript using the + operator?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know that if either one of my operands is a string, it should prefer string concatenation, but I get an integer.

```
        var number = 134324;
        var num_str = number + "";
       console.log(num_str);
```

Comment: with `console.log(typeof num_str);`, you get `'string'` as wanted.

Comment: I want to get "134324"

Comment: Maybe `console.log(JSON.stringify(num_str))` then.

Answer (score 2):

No it should not return string .. as you are printing it in console it looks like integer but try using

```
var number = 134324;
        var num_str = number + "";
       console.log(num_str);
        typeof(num_str);
```

It will display that your answer is string ... :) hope you satisfied ..

Answer (score 1):

You can use toString() method.

```
num_str = number.toString()
```